# Adding line numbers to table <td> using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am a beginner with javascript. I have an html table with contenteditable data, I would like to use javascript to add numbering next to each line inside the "contenteditable" column after entering TAB :
[image]

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true" >First column</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome!
In the example you gave, there is one row.
Does "line" mean row?

Comment: I mean by lines, the ones appearing after entering tabs within the "contenteditable" <td>...

Comment: Okay - so, when the column is edited with and has carriage returns, you want to know how many lines after editing?

Comment: I want to display the number of each line (defined by entering TAB) next to the column content, as shown in the photo I just added to my question...

Comment: It seems like what you really want to do is add rows under a column heading and then count the number of rows added. If not, could you explain what exactly you are trying to accomplish? When I put this code into an html file, tab does not create a new line.

Comment: For me, tab actually creates new line... Exactly, what I would like to do is to add rows numbering inside an editable column. After each tab, add a new line number next to that new line

Comment: Show us how for you "tab actually creates new line".
Look into CSS ::before.
And/or, add a background image with line numbers.
Or, JavaScript to break the content, manipulate, and re-render...

Comment: Thanks ! ... I have added a photo to my question explaining what I would like to have.

Answer (score 0):

If by "line number", you mean "column number", this will work:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td contenteditable="true" >First column</td>
        <td contenteditable="true" >Second column</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
let index = 1
document.querySelectorAll('td')
  .forEach((td) => {
    td.innerText += " " + index
    index += 1
})
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not satisfy what I meant. I think my question lacks some more clarification. I mean by lines, the ones  inside each of the "contenteditable" <td> after entering tabs...